# parse out all combinations of words

Tags: string, parsing

I need to take a string of words, could be any amount of words and create an array of all possible combinations from the first word to the last word.

example input: (the input could be any amount of words, the delimiter is a space

"word1 word2 word3"

output:

```
1: word1
2: word1 word2
3: word1 word2 word3
4: word2
5: word2 word3
6: word3
```

any language is fine, but prefer c#

Comment: did you miss "word1 word3 word2" and some others combinations on purpose ? edit: ie do you mean combinations in the mathematical sense (that is to say, not a permutation)?

Comment: "word1 word3" is in-order but it's missing

Answer (score 1):

Haskell, just because it's beautiful (compared to the C-family at least) and you said any language:

```
combinations []     = [[]]
combinations (x:xs) = (combinations xs) ++ map (x:) (combinations xs)
```

Can be invoked like this:

```
combinations ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
```

or like this, if you really have to pass it a space-separated string:

```
combinations (words "word1 word2 word3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a homework problem.

Use string.split and then use two for loops.

```
var wordlist = "word1 word2 word3";
var words = wordlist.Split(' ');
var wordList = new List<string>();
for( var i=0; i<words.Length; i++ )
{
  var currentWord = words[i];
  wordList.add( currentWord );
  for( var j=i+1; j<words.Length; j++ )
  {
    currentWord += " " + words[j];
    wordList.Add( currentWord );
  }
}
```

You might also use string.Format or a StringBuilder if you want to be Melvin and get extra credit...

Comment: This helped alot, but there was one issue, the second for loop needs to be this: for( var j=i+1; j<words.Length; j++)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is

1. Count from `1` to `(1<<w)-1` inclusive where `w` is the number of words.
2. For each of the values of the counter consider the individual bits of the value, if the n-th bit is set then consider the n-th word, otherwise skip it.

Answer (score 0):

The haskell-solution translated to C#:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Combinations(IEnumerable<string> words) {
  if (words.Count() == 0) {
    return new string[][] { new string[0] };
  } else {
    var x = words.First();
    var xs = words.Skip(1);
    var combinations = Combinations(xs);
    return combinations.Concat(combinations.Select(s => new string[] { x }.Concat(s)));
  }
}
```

And the string-parsing one:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Combinations(string str) {
   return Combinations(str.Split(" "));
}
```